# Am I allowed to use "overflow: hidden;" for Adsense ad

Tags: html, adsense

(So I tried to post this question in Google Adsense support forum but got the following message "The maximum number of entries has been exceeded. Please try again later." even though it's my first post.)

I have a 728x90 ad within a div with the property `border-top-left-radius: 10px;`.
There is therefore a tiny overflow with the ad. Am I allowed to use `overflow: hidden;`. Or does this violate with the TOS?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about legality.

Comment: If any part of the ad is blocked from view, then you can't do it. The advertiser pays to have all the content visible.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can.

From [AdSense program policies](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/48182?ctx=as2&rd=3&ref_topic=1261918#beh),

> **Ad behavior**
>
> Publishers are permitted to make modifications to the AdSense ad code
>   so long as those modifications do not artificially inflate ad
>   performance or harm advertisers.

But better try to ask it again in Google Adsense support forum.